# How can we create an add to calendar button for various calendars

Tags: javascript, email, calendar

I wanted to create buttons for "add to calendar" for various calendars like gmail, outlook , and apple calendar. I know we can create the .ics file and insert those into button links. is there a script or better way to create these ics files ?

Comment: Something like this would probably do the job. https://www.addevent.com/add-to-calendar-button

Comment: is this for a browser only or does it work in a email template as well.

Comment: email clients won't run Javascript, so website only. You may need to think about expanding your question to include more context.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and packed all of my learning in one open-source repository at https://github.com/jekuer/add-to-calendar-button

The code is quite well documented and since this is a quite open question, I would recommend to check the following function in https://github.com/jekuer/add-to-calendar-button/blob/main/assets/js/atcb.js :

- atcb_generate_google
- atcb_generate_yahoo
- atcb_generate_microsoft
- atcb_generate_teams
- atcb_generate_ical

Or use the package as it is :)